# "That's it" versus "That's that"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Example one:

> Once they give their money, **that's it**, they don't want to hear it anymore.
>
> Once they give their money, **that's that**, they don't want to hear it anymore.

Example two:

> Today's lesson will only cover the introduction about the course. And **That's it**
>
> Today's lesson will only cover the introduction about the course. And **That's that**

Are the above examples with ***That's that*** correct? I feel that ***That's it*** and ***That's that*** has a little difference in connotation and ***That's it*** has a larger arrays of meaning and can be used in more situations that the other, is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right in that there's a little difference in nuance, but not a lot.

*That's that* to me means **End of Discussion.**

*That's it* to me means *that's all*. I do believe there is more flexibility.

> You can have either grape or orange juice to drink, and that's all.
>   You're grounded and that's that.

I kind of like, "That'll do."